# How to include added and removed files to a unified diff of a CL in perforce

Tags: diff, patch, perforce

I want to create a unified diff or patch using `p4 describe -du` or `p4 diff2 -u`, to apply later with `patch` utility. But the problem I encounter that these commands skip the content of added/removed files.

The closest I found so far is to use `p4 describe -adu` and then process added files content part with python script. But even then the content of the deleted files is skipped.